# How to get your combo-box to select the item selected

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-access-2010

I've manipulated and tried a different way about going about something. I have a combo-box(Coding_drop_down) on a form(Coding Pop Up).

I previously had taken over maintenance for this database from someone else so everything was pre-existing. The combo-box itself had a Value List in it and referenced that when clicking the drop down arrow. However I've since changed that and bound it to a table that I created (for something past this). Now when I go to the drop down I get those specific values that I did before only loaded from a table rather than a Value List. The problem is that when selecting the value it does not select. Am I missing something or does the VBA need to be manipulated ???

VBA Code for the combo-box:

```
Private Sub Command1_click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command1_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

    stDocName = "Query to do easier coding"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

Exit_Command1_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command1_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command1_Click

End Sub
```

The code for the Button :

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command7_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String
    stDocName = "Query to do easier coding"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, stDocName

    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_Command7_Click:
    Exit Sub
```

And the on Click event of the actual Combo-box:

```
Private Sub Coding_drop_down_Click()
Dim test As String
test = Me.Coding_drop_down
MsgBox test

End Sub
```

Comment: Command1 indicates that the code is for a Button and not for a Combo-Box. I also do not see that the code would reference any Combo-Box. So it's not clear to me where your problem really is. PS: you always should rename your controlls in a way that it indicates which control it is. Command1 isn't really a good name ;-)

Comment: I took this database over and there was NO comments in the VBA so it took me a few minutes to figure out that Command1 is referencing the Combo-box...... Command7 (yeah I know) is referencing the button. I added the VBA for the button above.

Comment: Are you talking about a UserForm when you say you have a Form and its called coding pop up?

Comment: Correct again I did not create this only just now taking over this.

Comment: I actually can't find Command1 ANYWHERE my apology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the combo-box was actually bound to something and that was the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so try this out for your comboBox it might give you a good start.  The items you want in the comboxBox are listed in the .addItem and they are added to the ComboBox once the form is started.  When you select the item it then stores the value in the first cell of the sheet you want.  If this is something that can help you out let me know and we can work towards helping with your problem.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ComboBox1
    .AddItem ("Item 1")
    .AddItem ("Item 2")
    .AddItem ("Item 3")
End With

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()


    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = ComboBox1.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason even after changing the Form name and the CboBox names adding the correct "Item" it still does not select =/

Comment: can you share the entire code for the user form in your question? what is the name of the Userform?

Comment: All of the VBA above is all that is on that particular form which is named (Coding Pop Up)...... I will state however that when trying to add that to the Form name for the .AddItem Sub that I could not find it ? So it appears as though it is Command1 somehow I think this may be where the problem is. That and this database was not built with any comments and bad naming convention.

Comment: I actually just figured out the issue of why it was not selecting !  It was bound to something that it shouldn't have been. I'm now getting an error though         RUN TIME '424' Object Required it points to a certain line of code in the Combo-box Sub.